# 2d array access with lua userdata

Tags: c, lua, lua-userdata

I am trying to write a lua library providing 2d arrays with the C api. I have followed the [tutorial](https://www.lua.org/pil/28.html) available on the lua website where it is demonstrated how to implement 1d arrays.
To add support for 2d arrays I have simply added a third argument to the get method, but it doesn't seems to be the right way to do it, it seems the third parameter is never sent to the get function.

Here's the C code:

```C
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lua.h>

typedef struct Array2d {
  size_t height, width;
  int data[];
} Array2d;

static int array2d_get(lua_State *L) {
  Array2d *arr = lua_touserdata(L, 1);
  size_t x = luaL_checkinteger(L, 2) - 1;
  size_t y = luaL_checkinteger(L, 3) - 1;
  luaL_argcheck(L, arr != NULL, 1, "'array' expected");
  luaL_argcheck(L, x >= 0 && x < arr->width, 2, "x is not in [1,width]");
  luaL_argcheck(L, y >= 0 && y < arr->height, 3, "y is not in [1,height]");
  lua_pushinteger(L, arr->data[x + y * arr->width]);
  return 1;
}

static int array2d_size(lua_State *L) {
  Array2d *arr = lua_touserdata(L, 1);
  luaL_argcheck(L, arr != NULL, 1, "'array' expected");
  lua_pushinteger(L, arr->width * arr->height);
  return 1;
}

static int array2d_new(lua_State *L) {
  size_t width = luaL_checkinteger(L, 1);
  size_t height = luaL_checkinteger(L, 2);
  size_t nbytes = sizeof(Array2d) + width * height * sizeof(int);
  Array2d *arr = lua_newuserdata(L, nbytes);
  arr->width = width;
  arr->height = height;
  luaL_getmetatable(L, "lib.arr");
  lua_setmetatable(L, -2);

  for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
    arr->data[i] = 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg libarr_f[] = {{"new", array2d_new}, {NULL, NULL}};
static const struct luaL_Reg libarr_m[] = {
    {"__index", array2d_get}, {"__len", array2d_size}, {NULL, NULL}};

int luaopen_libarr(lua_State *L) {
  luaL_newmetatable(L, "lib.arr");
  luaL_setfuncs(L, libarr_m, 0);
  luaL_newlib(L, libarr_f);
  return 1;
}
```

And here is the lua code:

```lua
local libarr = require "libarr"
local width=3
local height=3
arr = libarr.new(width,height)
for i=1,width do
        for j=1,height do
                print(arr[i][j])
        end
end
```

And when I run the code I get following message, which shows that the get function never received the third argument:

```
lua: main.lua:7: bad argument #3 to 'index' (number expected, got no value)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in metamethod 'index'
        main.lua:7: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

Does someone knows what I am doing wrong? Any clues on how to make it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does someone knows what I am doing wrong?

`arr[i][j]` does not invoke `getmetatable(arr).__index(arr, i, j)` as you seem to be expecting it to.

Rather, it invokes `getmetatable(arr).__index(arr, i)[j]`. So `getmetatable(arr).__index`, which resolves to `array2d_get`, is called with `arr, i`, **not** `arr, i, j`, which throws the error you're seeing.

If this didn't throw an error, the return value of this would be indexed with `j`.

> Any clues on how to make it works?

You might be tempted to try something like `arr[i, j]`, but unlike some other languages, indexing in Lua only allows exactly a single value; this is a syntax error.

I see 4 options to fix this:

##### Getter

Write a "`get`" "method" rather than "overloading" `[]`. That "method" can take parameters `i, j` then: `arr:get(i, j)` desugars to `getmetatable(arr)["get"](arr, i, j)`. You just need to set the metatable up such that `getmetatable(arr)["get"]` resolves to your `array2d_get` function (for example by setting `__index = {get = array2d_get}`).

I would also argue that this is probably cleaner as you add methods to your 2d arrays. Otherwise, something like `arr:push(42)` will always first have to check whether `"push"` is a valid index, then resolve to the method if it isn't. This is also not great for performance (of method calls).

##### Array of Arrays

Move from your "2d array" userdata back to "1d array of 1d arrays", then everything will work naturally, albeit with somewhat more memory overhead (and negative implications e.g. for cache locality and GC pressure, so this also comes at a runtime cost).

##### "Row" Type

You could make `arr[y]` return a "row" userdata object for the y-th row (effectively just a fancy pointer) which, when indexed, would give you the x-th element in the row.

Creating such "row" objects for every indexing operation might be a problem performance-wise, however.

##### Compound Index Type

For the sake of completeness, you could also use a table (or a userdata object, or a string, or a closure...) to implement something like `arr[{x, y}]` or `arr[Index2D(x, y)]`. If you need performance, this is probably a bad idea as each indexing operation requires creating a garbage table then.